# Why I can't parse timestamp in pyarrow?

Tags: python, json, parquet, pyarrow

I have a JSON file with that variable:

```
"BirthDate":"2022-09-05T08:08:46.000+00:00"
```

And I want to create parquet based on that file. I prepared fixed schema for pyarrow where *BirthDate* is a `pa.timestamp('s')`. And when I trying to convert that file I got error:

```
ERROR:root:Failed of conversion of JSON to timestamp[s], couldn't parse:2022-09-05T08:08:46.000+00:00
```

My pyarrow code:

```
parquet_file = pyarrow_json.read_json(json_file, parse_options=pyarrow_json.ParseOptions(
                explicit_schema=prepared_schema,
                unexpected_field_behavior='ignore'))
```

I have also some files with different types of timestamp (for example without that "+") and it's work fine then.

How can I convert it, and where is a problem with this specific type?

Comment: The answer is correct, but I think it could still be an improvement to give a better error message about this and hint to that solution -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-18107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me using `pa.field("BirthDate", pa.timestamp('ms'))`.

I think it's because your timestamps have got millisecond precision (even though they have their milliseconds set to zero)

```py
import pyarrow.json as pyarrow_json
import pyarrow as pa

prepared_schema = pa.schema([pa.field("BirthDate", pa.timestamp('ms'))])

parquet_file = pyarrow_json.read_json(
    json_file,
    parse_options=pyarrow_json.ParseOptions(
        explicit_schema=prepared_schema,
        unexpected_field_behavior='ignore')
)
```